React Native Dropdown State Not Updating Visually Despite Logging Correct State
I'm working with a React Native dropdown where selecting an item updates the state as expected, but the UI doesn’t visually reflect the new state immediately. When I log the state in the onChange function, it shows the updated state. If I set the selected value states to empty arrays ([]) initially, the dropdown takes the first item by default.
I need help making sure the dropdown visually reflects the selected item.
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
    const [customers, setCustomers] = useState([]);
    const [sizes, setSizes] = useState([]);
    const [units, setUnits] = useState([]);
 
    const [selectedProduct, setSelectedProduct] = useState('');
    const [selectedSize, setSelectedSize] = useState('');
    const [selectedUnit, setSelectedUnit] = useState('');
    const [selectedCustomer, setSelectedCustomer] = useState('');

    const handleProductChange = async (item) => {
        setSelectedProduct(item.label);
        try {
            const response = await axios.get(`${url}/unit-masters/${item.unitId}`);
            const unitData = response.data;
            setSelectedUnit(unitData.unitName);
            setUnits([{ label: unitData.unitName, value: unitData.id }]);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching unit data:", error);
        }
    };

    const handleCustomerChange = (item) => {
        setSelectedCustomer(item.label);
    };

    const handleSizeUnitChange = useCallback((type, item) => {
        if (type === 'size') {
            setSelectedSize(item.label);
        } else if (type === 'unit') {
            setSelectedUnit(item.label);
        }
    }, []);

    return (
        <View>
            <Dropdown
                data={customers}
                search
                maxHeight={300}
                labelField="label"
                valueField="value"
                placeholder="Select Customer"
                searchPlaceholder="Search..."
                value={selectedCustomer}
                onChange={handleCustomerChange}
            />
            <Dropdown
                data={products}
                search
                maxHeight={300}
                labelField="label"
                valueField="value"
                placeholder="Enter Product Name"
                value={selectedProduct}
                onChange={handleProductChange}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

When I select an item from the dropdown, the onChange function logs the updated state correctly, but the dropdown doesn’t visually update to show the selected item. However, setting selectedProduct or selectedCustomer to an empty array ([]) initially results in the first dropdown item being selected by default, which isn’t desired behavior.
What I've Tried:
I ensured the onChange function correctly logs the changed state.
I tried setting the initial state to [], but it selects the first dropdown item by default.
currently i have to tap two time to update state
Expected Behavior: The dropdown should visually display the selected item without requiring an initial [] state setup.
Question: What adjustments are needed for the dropdown to visually reflect the selected item upon state update?
